# How to pass "If-Modified-Since" in a http request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, httpwebrequest, if-modified-since

I am getting a collection of books from an external resource. For that i am using a call like

```
response = book_resource.get_books({headers:{"If-Modified-Since" => last-update-date.httpdate}})
```

In last-update-date i saved the value of last-modified from the header of previous response.
But i am always getting the status code as 200 and instead of 304 not modified.But when i tried with etag using the following code.

```
 response = book_resource.get_books({headers:{"If-None-Match" => "etag"}})
```

The above is working fine and returning 304 not modified. Kindly help me what i am missing with modified since

Comment: make sure the date format is exactly the same as required. As something similar happened to me using amazon api and was stuck for days until i realised just  needed to add hh:ss (complete datetime stamp).

Answer (score 0):

Which tool you use to send HTTP request? Lookup docs to see how to send customized header. For example, [here](https://github.com/httprb/http#adding-headers) is how to add headers in httprb.